# How to draw a rectangle on a form picturebox from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have 2 forms.

1. form = form1
2. form = form2

When pressing  a button in form1, form2 shows up.
What I want is pressing a button in form2 draws a rectangle on to form1 picturebox.

I Wrote an event handler function for button clicked in Form2 to be handled in Form1, but in handler I can't draw anything in form1's picturebox.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: @parapura rajkumar Yes, but could'nt succeed. Wrote an event handler fonction for button clicked in Form2 to be handled in Form1. But in handler I can't draw the anything in form1's picturebox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your event code on Form1 where you are receiving the button click event from Form2, try this:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
  g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(10, 10, 32, 32));

pictureBox1.Invalidate();
```